# How to handle back to back alerts on selenium webdriver automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, alerts

Scenario:

- On Perform Click -> Alert1 is displayed
- On Accept Alert1 -> Alert2 is displayed

I am able to accept alert1 but when I write code to handle alert2 also then None of alerts are accepted.
Tried different from Google but nothing works

Different combination with thread.sleep and wait etc but nothing works.

Code 1:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
alert.accept(); // For Alert1 
Thread.sleep(5000); 
alert.accept(); // For alert2
```

Code 2:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(5000); 
alert.accept(); // For Alert1 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();   
Switchtoframe(0); 
Alert alert1 = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
Thread.sleep(5000); //test 
alert1.accept(); // For alert2
```

Comment: and your code??

Comment: //Code 1:
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 alert.accept(); // For Alert1 
 Thread.sleep(5000);
alert.accept(); // For alert2

//Code 2
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 alert.accept(); // For Alert1 
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
Switchtoframe(0);
Alert alert1 = driver.switchTo().alert();
 Thread.sleep(5000); //test
alert1.accept(); // For alert2

Comment: it would be nice if you put it on your post instead

Comment: I am new user and was stopped by format issue for adding code on Post

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from the comment (hard to read what is going on due to java comments), you can try something like this:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert1 = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    alert1.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // No alert exists
}

try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert2 = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    alert2.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // No alert exists
}
```

Don't think you really need the waits, but it was in the demo.

Comment: It worked now.. I wonder what was issue yesterday. Thank You very much. Appreciate it.. as I was struggling for past 3-4 days :)

Comment: @pratap88bhanu, Glad to help. If you wouldn't mind, can you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Each alert is a separate entity so you can't get the first one and then `.accept()` it twice. The fact that the second code block didn't work makes me think that you probably need a brief wait after dismissing the first for the second to appear. I would write something like this.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
```

The `wait` returns what was waited on... in this case the `Alert` instance so you can chain `.accept()`. This can be repeated for the second instance also.

---

I forgot to mention... you shouldn't need all those sleeps and they are a bad practice anyway. You can do some googling and reading to get all the details as to why. Use `WebDriverWait` instead.